# What is the purpose of cached Assetic config?

Tags: symfony, assetic

I'm doing some research into Assetic and asset-management generally in Symfony.  One thing I've noticed in the cache folder for my project (which uses Assetic) in the dev environment is the folders `assetic\config`, with that `config` folder having subfolders 0-9 and a-f.

Inside each of those subfolders are a number of PHP files with hashes for filenames and contents like this (the comment is part of the file):

```
// MyBundle:FolderName/twigfilename.html.twig
return array (
);
```

**General questions:** What is the point of these files?  What do they do?  Will they ever have more interesting content than this?  (I've never found any that do.)

**More specific question:** Unless `use_controller` is set to false ([ref](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-dev-environment)), assets are loaded dynamically every time, so - as I understand it - you shouldn't need to clear the cache to force an update of your assets.  My general rule-of-thumb is "don't bother clearing the cache for things to do with assets, just do that for Twig or PHP-file things".  Given that Assetic obviously puts *something* in the cache, is this still a good rule-of-thumb?